# Daily Email Limits For Customer Emails

Tags: email, limits

we currently send 2,500 emails to our customers (they all have accounts). These emails include invoices, appointments etc. These are operational emails on a daily basis. We are ramping up these emails to possibly 10,000 to 15,000 per day. We will not be able to send these. Do we have to use an external app for this as SF cannot do this. Compared to many large companies on SF, we are a medium sized company - what do other companies do? thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1):

As per [this knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312442&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1):

- the 2500 emails limit only applies to emails sent using "external email addresses" (actually, that means emails sent using an email address rather than using a recipient object).
- if you ensure that all email sending is done using User objects as the recipients there are no limits at all.

It comes down to how you invoke the email sending. As long as you pass the ID of the User object that has the email address as a field within it (using `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`'s `setTargetObjectId` for example) the sending doesn't count towards the limits. If you get the email address out of the object then pass that instead (using `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`'s `setToAddresses` for example) this *will* count against the limits.

Note that uses of `setTargetObjectId` with other types of object than User do, unfortunately, count towards limits (something I forgot about when originally answering this quesion). The main problem here is inconsistent and unclear documentation!

NB: If you have a list of email addresses, you can minimize the number of counted email sends to those where users or community users **don't match** these addresses. To find those that **do match** use a query like:

```
SELECT Id, Email, Contact.Email FROM User WHERE Email IN :emails OR Contact.Email IN :emails
```

This allows use of the `Id` from the `User` object when sending, via `setTargetObjectId`. Not all email addresses would be mapped so you must find any not covered by the returned data and send emails to those directly (using limits).

Comment: thanks Phil. I am using the customer account's email address. The fact that they are customers on our system should mean that they are not external email addresses or am I understanding this incorrectly?

Comment: I updated my answer to cover this more explicitly.

Comment: N.B. `setTargetObjectId` includes `Lead` as well as `User` and `Contact`

Comment: @cropredy, I aligned my answer fully withe valid target objects now.

Comment: thanks Phil/Cropredy, we hold the email address in the Accounts object. If I pass the Account ID, will that just pick up the email address field?

Comment: sorry, ignore last comment:  thanks Phil/Cropredy, we hold the email address in a custom object called EmailNotifications__c. If I pass the EmailNotifications ID, will that just pick up the email address field?

Comment: Sadly, no. You might need to change your object model to do it a different way.

Comment: ok thanks. Unfortunately, the email template information uses several objects; Accounts for the customer info, Work orders and Service Appointments for the job details and costs etc.

Comment: Could you not, for example, replace the email address field on your email notification object with a Contact Lookup so you can then pass that Contact ID (literally the lookup field value) to the send mail? That way the email won't count towards limits.

Comment: This is what I meant by changing your object model.

Comment: that sounds good. We currently don't use the contacts object but we could use Account, where the email address also resides. Thanks for the further help on this Phil.

Comment: Account is only good if it is a Person Account. That is a feature you have to specifically enable and doesn't sound like it is something you should do if you already use Account. I strongly suggest simply using a Contact. It's trivial to do. Again, replace the Account email with a lookup to a Contact as well.

Comment: they are Person Accounts. I will look at implementing what you have suggested. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, OK. If you are already using Person Accounts there should be no issue. Good luck!

Comment: thanks Phil. Further research shows that the limit for sending emails is limited to 5,000 if using Apex and that is what we use. is this your understanding?

Comment: No, not if you use the SingleEmailMessage with a target object ID. Yes, the documentation is very vague and confusing, but after updating our managed package about 8 months ago from using setToAddress etc. to using setTargetObjectId all our usage of email limits disappeared.

Comment: that's great news. Yes, you are correct about the documentation being vague. Just a bit of background, we have been using SF for about 18 months. It was initially set up by contractors who replicated/improved our old VB system. I'm a vb programmer currently learning SF :-)

Comment: Apologies, I tracked back to where we did our code revisions in our package and found we had to map to Users and could not use Contacts directly since they count towards limits. Annoying :(

Comment: hi Phil, couldn't get it to work with contactID and I've just seen your last comment. Can I assume then that you never overcame the limit issue? thanks

Comment: We overcame it in the context of communities by finding the Users for the Contacts and using those Users' IDs instead. We also ensured to convert email addresses to Users (indirectly via Contacts) as needed to minimise use of limits.

Comment: thanks for the reply Phil, if you don't mind, could you explain further what you mean by 'finding the Users for the Contacts' and converting the email addresses to Users? thanks again

Comment: Given a list of email addresses you can do a query like `SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email IN :emails OR Contact.Email IN :emails` then use the Id from the user object when sending. Not all email addresses would be mapped so you find any not covered by the returned data and send emails to those directly (using limits).

Comment: ok thanks very much Phil