# Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected: Messaging.SingleEmailMessage but was: List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>

Tags: email-template

The below code gave me his error: Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected: Messaging.SingleEmailMessage but was: List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>
How do I rectify this?

Code:

```
public class TestEmailNotification {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void sendMail() {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        EmailTemplate templateid = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = :'xyz' LIMIT 1];
        System.debug(templateid);
        if (templateid != null) {

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            mail.setToAddresses(getEmailAddresses());
            mail.setTemplateId(templateid.Id);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName(UserInfo.getUserName());

//mail.setSubject('This is the subject');

//mail.setPlainTextBody('This is the body.');

            mails.add(mail);
            Messaging.sendMail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {
                    mails
            });
        }
    }

    public static List<String> getEmailAddresses() {

        List<String> idList = new List<String>();

        List<String> mailToAddresses = new List<String>();

        Group g = [SELECT (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMembers) FROM Group WHERE Name = 'abc'];

        for (GroupMember gm : g.GroupMembers) {

            idList.add(gm.UserOrGroupId);

        }

        User[] usr = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id IN :idList];

        for (User u : usr) {
            System.debug(u);
            System.debug(u.Email);
            mailToAddresses.add(u.Email);

        }

        return mailToAddresses;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Throwing this into an IDE highlights the error as being on the following line:

```
Messaging.sendMail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {
    mails
});
```

That's because you're trying to statically initialize an array from a declared sequence of array entries but you're actually sending in the array of entries as an array.

Change this line to:

```
Messaging.sendMail(mails);
```

Another point worth noting; the emails you are sending will count towards your external email daily limit even though the email addresses are coming from `User` records. Why? Because you are using the `setToAddresses` method instead of the `setTargetObjectId` method. If you switch to the latter, these sent emails will not count to your daily email limit. See this [previous Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/314306/daily-email-limits-for-customer-emails/314311#314311) for more detail.